# Export functions from current session

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have created a `function` in my current PowerShell session. Now I want to save it for later use. How?

For instance, how can I use this in subsequent sessions?

```
function xfirefox {
    Start-Process firefox.exe $args
}
```

I know I just put it into my `profile`. I would like though, to be able to run something like `Export-Function xfirefox myFunctions.txt` instead.

Comment: You need to build a profile and save it http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps put this in your profile. Remove -WhatIf when ready.

```
function say ($msg) {
    Write-Host $msg
}

function Export-Function ($Name) {
    $fx = (gcm -Name $Name -CommandType Function)
    if ($fx) {
@" 
function $($fx.Name) {
    $($fx.Definition)}
"@ | Out-File -FilePath $profile -Append -Encoding ascii -WhatIf
    }
}

Export-Function say
```

Comment: This is a neat idea that I haven't tried yet. Thank you.